# Adding custom icons to font-awesome

Tags: font-awesome

It seems that font-awesome was supporting custom icons with detailed instructions how to create and submit your own icon but that information is no longer available on their website. Does this mean that this is not supported any longer and that you can only request an icon creation that will be done by font-awesome team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) doesn't support direct submissions any longer.

They used to provide a grid template for submissions, but as you point out it has been removed and suggestions/support for new icons are logged [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues?labels=feature&state=open) on Github (I have supported a couple of requests myself and receive updates when others log their support too).

It is possible to subset font-awesome icons using [icnfnt.com](http://www.icnfnt.com/) (which is the officially supported solution).

You can also subset and combine font-awesome with other fonts using [fontello.com](http://fontello.com/), essentially combining icons into one font-set that you can use in your projects.

Answer (score 4):

Try https://icomoon.io/ - you can add FontAwesome (along with other librariest out there, similar to icnfnt.com) and then add your own custome SVGs and export them all as a single font.